# React-Native wrap Images within text and display

Tags: react-native

I need to create a react-native screen that **displays questions that has images inline**.

So the View will basically have text and images repeatedly, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: your question is too broad and also opinion based. I suggest you read [How to ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague, but might it be as straight forward as this...

```
<View>
    <Text>Some Text</Text>
    <Image
      style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
      source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
    />
    <Text>Some Text</Text>
    <Image
      style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
      source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
    />
    <Text>Some Text</Text>
    <Image
      style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
      source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
    />
</View>
```

You can also do this, if you want the text to be on top of the image...

```
<Image
  style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
  source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
>
    <Text>Some Text</Text>
</Image>
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, the images have to be inline. A question can have images in between the texts